# How to access Text Field Data in CustomViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My Custom View Cell looks like the following http://img34.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110210at627.png/

```
@interface AddSiteAddressCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UITextField *street;
    IBOutlet UITextField *city;
    IBOutlet UITextField *province;
    IBOutlet UITextField *postal;
    IBOutlet UITextField *country;
    IBOutlet UITextField *siteName;

}
@property (nonatomic,retain)UITextField *siteName;
@end


@implementation AddSiteAddressCell

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"%@",street);    
}
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state.
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

AddSiteViewController.m

-

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        static NSString *MyIndentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
        MyIndentifier = @"tblCellView";
        //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        AddSiteAddressCell *cell = (AddSiteAddressCell *)[add_site dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIndentifier];

        if(cell == nil) {

            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddSiteAddressCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = nameCell;
        }
        return cell;


    }else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
    static NSString *MyIndentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    MyIndentifier = @"tblCellView";
    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    AddSiteAddressCell *cell = (AddSiteAddressCell *)[add_site dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIndentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddSiteAddressCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = addressCell;
    }
        return cell;
    }
    /*static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...*/

    return nil;
}





    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
        AddSiteAddressCell *cell =  (AddSiteAddressCell *)[add_site cellForRowAtIndexPath:[indexPath row]];                                                   
        self.test = cell.siteName.text;
        NSLog(@"%@",self.test);
    }
```

MY full view looks like this:

http://img29.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110211at940.png/
This is what my View looks like. 2 sections with 1 row each and 1 custom cell each

Thats code from my CustomTableViewCell

I am wondering how I can access my text field in my table controller to save the data that is entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when do u want to access it?
you should make property for your text field (e.g siteName), and then if you have the IndexPath of your cell, u can use:

```
AddSiteAddressCell *myCell=(AddSiteAddressCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:MyIndexPath];
myCell.siteName....
```

Comment: Well This data is going to be sent to a webservice, So I want to send the data when i press my save button in my navigation bar. I see though what you mean I will try with the property and get back to you

Comment: If you have some rows maybe u should save your current IndexPath, and set it in -     (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I try and do NSLog after I enter it and I get a null back. Any Ideas why?

Comment: did u enter the details and then clicked again on the row?

Comment: wait, did u @syntisize your property?

Comment: Ok it works thanks i was missing hte synthesize and the line above fixed the issue